# Django: How to make all form fields hidden?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a Django form class with around 8 fields. How do I dynamically make **all** these form fields hidden in one of my views?

Sample:

```
class FormName(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs="class":"validate[required,first_name]","tabindex":"4"}), required=True)
    middle_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs="class":"validate[middle_name]","tabindex":"5"}), required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs="class":"validate[required,last_name]","tabindex":"6"}), required=True)
```

The reason I want to do this is because I would be using the same form in one of the sign up pages and then again use a similar form elsewhere, where I want these form fields to be hidden. I don't want to create a separate class duplicating the same fields with "widget=forms.HiddenInput()".

Comment: Why not separate class? Could you explain?

Comment: I can have a second class having the same 8 fields but instead of TextInput, I can use HiddenInput. But I thought that would be a complicated way (and I also would be duplicating some code). Was looking for easier ways, if any. Is there any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases when you need a form with hidden inputs, you can notify your form, by passing additional variable to the `__init__` method like: `form = FormName(is_hidden=True)`. And your form might be looking like follows:

```
class FormName(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs="class":"validate[required,first_name]","tabindex":"4"}), required=True)
    middle_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs="class":"validate[middle_name]","tabindex":"5"}), required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs="class":"validate[required,last_name]","tabindex":"6"}), required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_hidden = kwargs.pop('is_hidden', None)
        super(FormName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_hidden:
            self.fields['first_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            self.fields['middle_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            self.fields['last_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

In all other cases you can use your form as ussual, without passing `is_hidden` variable, and it will be using default widgets you defined.

Also, you can iterate over `self.fields` dictionary, and make all your field widgets hidden without having to override each of them manualy

Comment: I tried your solution. I am getting the following exception:AttributeError: 'FormName' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: Great. Thanks. It works. Fixed some code in the answer to be in sync with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using class based views, if you think you're gonna use something over and over again, for example : forms. Your views should look like this:

views.py:

```
class BaseView(object):

    def __init__(self, request = None , form  = None, <#define anything you want here, like model = None or template = None>):
        if form:
            self.form = form
        else:
            self.form = FormName

        if #AnythingIWant:
            self.anythingiwant = anythingiwant
        else:
            self.anythingiwant = defaultofanythingiwant

    def __call__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return self.POST_handler()
        else:
            return self.GET_handler()

    def POST_handler(self):
        #method to handle post request

    def GET_handler(self):
        #method to handle get request
        #because u want specific form reusable just add:
        # context = {'form' : self.form()}
        # then render a template with the context above

    def extra_context(self):
        return {}
```

Later if you want to use that form, just inherit `BaseView`, like :

```
class IndexView(BaseView):
    #blahblahblah
```

And if you want to add something in your `GET_handler()` use `extra_context`, for example if you want to add another form :

views.py :

```
class ProfileView(BaseView):

    def extra_context(self):
        form = MyCustomForm()
        context = {'custom_form' : form}
        return context
```

as for urls.py:

`url(r'^$', ProfileView(), name='profile_view'),`

if you want to change the default form just override it like this :

`url(r'^$', ProfileView(form = MyCustomCustomForm), name='profile_view'),`

now you can use `MyCustomCustomForm` in every views that inherit `BaseView`. Good thing about using class based views is you can do that to everything, not just form, maybe you want to use some model over and over again